# Heroku H13 error a way to fix it?

Tags: heroku

I have an application running on Heroku, sometimes this error appear :

```
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `block in call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1416:in `synchronize'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-    1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-10-03T17:01:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

So what can I do ? ...

**Edit : add gemfile**

```
source :rubygems

# use Heroku Toolbelt instead
# gem "heroku"

# sinatra main library
gem "sinatra"

# sinatra plugin for localization
gem "sinatra-r18n"

gem "resolv-ipv6favor"

# Json
gem "json"

# rack middleware csrf protection
gem "rack_csrf"

# database handler | orm
gem "pg"
gem "sequel"
gem "sequel_sluggable"

gem "unicode_utils"
gem "sanitize"
gem "fog"
gem "mail"
gem "thin"

# Full system log
gem 'remote_syslog_logger'

group :development do
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "sinatra-reloader"
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

Comment: [Heroku Docs on error codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response) suggest that its a rare error in some gem you are using

Comment: What's the top of the error message, before `.../lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb`?

Comment: I have provided an answer to a similar question which may be of help. [Heroku router errors H13 logged by LogEntries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954253/864651)